# Can't run grub suite

Tags: grub, initramfs

I'm trying to run Grub from a custom initramfs. Only Busybox, Grub, and an init are installed. Busybox and the init are able to be run. But when I run /usr/local/sbin/grub-install it says `command not found`. I compiled Grub with the `x86_64-unknown-linux` target. Why is this happening?

Comment: does `/usr/local/sbin/grub-install` exist? it's usually in `/usr/sbin`

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, I'm able to see the contents of it with cat.

Comment: Does `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` exist? Without it, you will be able to run only statically linked executables... and unless you specifically built your GRUB statically linked, it will need the dynamic linker/loader `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` and usually a number of other libraries.

Comment: `with cat`? so, it's a text file (presumably a shell script?) is it executable?

Comment: @JaromandaX ...or, as they perhaps are an embedded system developer, aren't scared of getting a bit of binary junk on their screen. That would be one way to prove that a file exists and is actually readable on a very minimal system.